Xpath Expression Clarity - Java Selenium
I was practicing my XPath by clicking on YouTube videos trending section. On the trending section I want to click on second video present irrespective of whichever video is present. I have written below XPath to target the second video. Below is the XPath using the text() method.
//*[contains(text(),"1 day ago")]

Now the above XPath targets all the 22 elements which contain the following text, i.e. 1 day ago. My objective is to target the second video. For that I have modified my XPath in the following way
//*[contains(text(),"1 day ago")][2]

Now when I write this it does not select any elements at all. Below is the image
Image 1 (View the rectangles I have marked in Red color).
However if I write
//*[contains(text(),"1 day ago")][1]

It targets all the 22 elements which contains the following text. Below is the image
Image 2 (View the rectangles I have marked in Red color)
I have two questions:

How should I modify my XPath so that it selects only the second element and why my current XPath, i.e. //*[contains(text(),"1 day ago")][2] is not working in the following scenario?

When writing the following XPath //*[contains(text(),"1 day ago")][1] why it is targeting all the 22 elements on the web page?


Thanks.

I can't explain the why but I can tell you that in this case the workaround is to enclose the locator in parentheses and then use the index, e.g.
(//*[contains(text(),'1 day ago')])[2]

That will work as you are expecting and get you what you want.

See here for a detailed explanation for both XPath 1.0 and 2.0 (and higher).

@kjhughes Thanks... I was hoping you would show up and save the day. :)

Thanks.   I just realized that the link  in my previous comment spoke more to contains(text(), ...), which has its own gotchas.   I probably should have linked to  this explanation of the difference between xpath[1] and (xpath)[1].

Thankyou it works as expected
